# MAMP : how to disable deprecated warnings

Tags: php, warnings, mamp

I'm trying to disable the deprecated warnings in MAMP. My MAMP php version is 5.5.18. The php.ini file is /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/conf/ as I can see in the phpinfo(). My problem is that nothing changes whatever I do in the php.ini.

I tried

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED
```

or even :

```
error_reporting  =  0
```

On the other hand

```
display_errors = Off
```

but the warnings are still displayed in my pages.

What did I miss?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to replace your deprecated functions.

Comment: This is not an option for me : this is a 8 years old site with thousands of mysql_db_query(). To much work to change this.

Comment: Is this on free mamp or MAMP PRO?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I had a php rule crushing the php.ini ones in one of the scripts. So this question in no more relevant.
I'm sorry for that.

Comment: I think I have your same problem if you have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111088/mamp-php-how-to-disable-php-warnings-messages-about-deprecated-functions ...what was the crushing rule? Maybe you could solve my problem too