# Mamp/PHP: how to disable PHP warnings messages about deprecated functions

Tags: php, mamp, ini

In my web app my boss wants me to use msql_* php functions but I can't even login because of PHP messages about these deprecated functions. How can I disable them in MAMP? Looking in this forum I've found the following rules to write inside php.ini

```
error_reporting  = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = On
disable_functions = "list of mysqli_* functions"
```

but this doesn't work. I've written this to all file php.ini of each php version contained in MAMP. The only thing that works is to put

```
display_errors = Off
```

but I can't use it like that otherwisw I won't even be able to see my programming/syntax error of other problems.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/2z8QedyF) is my php.ini of php 5.6.10 inside /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/

Do you have any ideas? I know I should use new functions and not deprecated ones but it's not up to me and I can't disable all error messages...

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have a solution for you, I'm sorry.
I did like that : in my .php files I put this code :

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED); // without "~"
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Within the TEMATRES program (which is the program I use) there is a configuration file: `config.tematres.php`. This file has the following line:

```
Ini_set ('display_errors', 'On');
Error_reporting (E_ALL);
```

I changed it to:

```
Ini_set ('display_errors', 'On');
Error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

And thus I was able to solve the problem.